How many atlas connections will pymongo create when deployed using Nuclio?
I am deploying a python application in Nuclio. This application uses Pymongo.
In the init_context, I create a Pymongo connection object like so:
setattr(context.user_data, 'atlas_connection',
    AtlasDB({'host' : 'mongodb+srv://c-----.t----.mongodb.net/D--------?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&appName=PDA',
    'authSource': '$external', 'authMechanism': 'MONGODB-X509', 'tlsCertificateKeyFile': "/path", 'tls': True, 'tlsCAFile': certifi.where()}))

The function.yaml has these configs:
replicas: 2
maxWorkers: 2

Based on Nuclio's documentation, each worker runs init_context for itself, meaning ideally, there will be 2x2=4 pymongo connection objects. Based on my understanding that means there will be 4 connections for my application to Atlas.
However in the atlas connection logs, there are 15 different connection IDs with the name 'PDA'. Why are there extra connections?
Also, in the connection logs, there are log lines with message 'connection accepted'. According to my understanding, connections (connection objects) are created only during init_context, so they should've all been created during the time nuclio function was deployed, however the connections for this application are still accepted well after the application is deployed (40-60 min). Who is creating these new connections?
Is some sort of connection pooling going on?
Documentations on how pymongo generates connections, and handles them, alongside nuclio's init_context would be greatly appreciated!
